# Direction field for dy/dx=-x/y

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\def\length{sqrt(1+(-x/y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3, 
view={0}{90},
title={$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
]
\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={1/(\length)}, v={(-x/y)/(\length)}, scale arrows=0.15}, -,samples=40] {0};
\addplot +[blue, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-sqrt(2):sqrt(2)]{sqrt(2-x^2)};
\addplot +[red, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-2:2]{sqrt(4-x^2)};
\addplot +[orange, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-sqrt(6):sqrt(6)]{sqrt(6-x^2)};
\addplot +[blue, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-sqrt(2):sqrt(2)]{-sqrt(2-x^2)};
\addplot +[red, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-2:2]{-sqrt(4-x^2)};
\addplot +[orange, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=-sqrt(6):sqrt(6)]{-sqrt(6-x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the direction field for $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$.  I have two problems.

1. How do I get the program to draw the vectors on the negative x-axis?
2. How do I draw circles of particular radius on the graph (the method I have come up with clearly doesn't work!)?

Thanks for any assistance.

Edit: I added in the document class as beamer, but it works just the same with article.

Comment: Please make your code compilable as a LaTeX document. E.g., state which document class you use and which packages must be loaded.

Comment: I can't compile it.

Comment: @Francesco Works fine here, just takes a few seconds.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your first point, could you try to clarify? For the circles, use e.g. `\addplot[red, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});`

Comment: If you try to compile the line with addplot3 with 25 samples rather than 40, it will fail to compile.  Presumably this is because the program has some difficulty dealing with the division by 0 when $y=0$?  In any case, the current code yields a distinct gap on the negative x-axis and almost too many (overlapping) vectors on the positive x-axis.  Also, thankyou very much for your suggestion regarding the circles.

Comment: I might say "of course", the arrows start at the same y-coordinate, but point in opposite directions. For x < 0 the point away from the line at y=0, for x > 0 the point towards that line. To avoid the overlapping you can scale them down a bit

Comment: Thank you again for your answer below.  I see now that my problem is that my code is not well adapted to what I'm aiming to do.  I'm trying to recreate the direction field diagram depicted https://youtu.be/XDhJ8lVGbl8?t=25m41s at 25:41, to be drawn without the isoclines.  But as you explained, the current method I have is going to have some (now obvious!) issues on the x-axis.  Are there any suggestions as to how to do this?  Your current answer below is definitely sufficient for my purposes and I'd also appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: As the lecturer says at a out 24:40, "the x-axis is not included". Anyways, I edited in something, don't know if it's anything like what you're after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\def\length{sqrt(1+(-x/y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3, 
view={0}{90},
title={$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
]
\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={1/(\length)}, v={(-x/y)/(\length)}, scale arrows=0.1}, -{Stealth[width=2pt,length=2pt]},samples=24,domain=-3:3] {0};
\addplot[blue, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[red, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[orange, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({3*cos(deg(x))},{3*sin(deg(x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this is sufficient for you. The circles are drawn as parametric plots, i.e. something of the form `\addplot ({r*cos(x)}, {r*sin(x)});`

The gap between the arrows for x < 0 is caused by the fact that the coordinate (x,y) refers to the start of the arrow as far as I can see, and as the arrows point in opposite directions (see image above), you get a gap there, and overlap for x > 0. Reducing the scaling of the arrows a bit fixes the overlapping problem. For the above image the number of samples is reduced to 24, if you really need 40 samples then you need to scale the arrows more, e.g.

```
\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={1/(\length)}, v={(-x/y)/(\length)}, scale arrows=0.07}, -{Stealth[width=1pt,length=1pt]},samples=40,domain=-3:3] {0};
```

One way of getting vertical arrows at the x-axis is to add separate quivers with u=0,v=±1. Perhaps the arrow scaling could be different.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\def\length{sqrt(1+(-x/y)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3, 
view={0}{90},
title={$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$},
xmin=-3,
xmax=3,
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
]
\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={1/(\length)}, v={(-x/y)/(\length)}, scale arrows=0.07}, -{Stealth[width=1pt,length=1pt]},samples=20,domain=-3:3] {0};

\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={0}, v={1}, scale arrows=0.05}, -{Stealth[width=1pt,length=1pt]},samples=10,samples y=1,domain=-3:-0.17,y domain=0] {0};
\addplot3[gray, quiver={u={0}, v={-1}, scale arrows=0.05}, -{Stealth[width=1pt,length=1pt]},samples=10,samples y=1,domain=-3:-0.17,y domain=0] {0};

\addplot[blue, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[red, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
\addplot[orange, samples=50, thick, no markers, domain=0:2*pi] ({3*cos(deg(x))},{3*sin(deg(x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Please see my comment in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that also addresses the problem of inconsistent spacing between arrows due to the fact that the `quiver` command in `pgfplots` places the tail of, rather than the center of, an arrow at each point of an equidistant grid.

To deal with the problem, one can first plot an arrow the usual way, and then plot a second arrow that points in a direction that is exactly opposite to that of the first, but without any arrowhead; that is, the second "arrow" is essentially just a line. Together, these two objects constitutes an arrow that points in the direction of the first arrow. This creates an illusion that the arrow is placed at the center of a point.

For example:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {f(\x) = -\x/\y;} % Define which function we're using
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        zmax = 1,
        zmin = 0,
        xtick = {-1,-0.5,...,1},
        axis equal image = true, % Unit vectors for both axes have the same length
        view = {0}{90}
        ]
        \addplot3[% Arrows' first-half
            blue,
            -stealth,
            domain  = -1:1,
            samples = 20,
            quiver  = {
                u=1/(2*sqrt(1^2 + f(x)^2)),
                v=f(x)/(2*sqrt(1^2 + f(x)^2)),
                scale arrows=0.075,
                },
        ] (x,y,0);
        \addplot3[% Arrow's second-half
            blue,
            domain  = -1:1,
            samples = 20,
            quiver  = {
                u=-1/(2*sqrt(1^2 + f(x)^2)),
                v=-f(x)/(2*sqrt(1^2 + f(x)^2)),
                scale arrows=0.075,
                },
        ] (x,y,0);
        \addplot [domain=-180:180, samples=100, color=red, thick] ({0.75*cos(x)},{0.75*sin(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The solution was inspired by a Matlab code by Tobias von Petersdorff of the University of Maryland. Here is [the link](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~petersd/246/dirfield.m).